# How to know the first day of the current week in Qt?

Tags: qt, date, calendar

I'm developing a software which must maintain one single SQL database record for each week. So each time it is started, it doesn't know if a record for the current week was already created (and so it needs only to update it) or not (and so needs to create that record). All records will have a "date-time" parameter with the day value corresponding to the first day of the correspondent week.

So, using Qt, how could I know if that week's record already exists or not? (in therms of algorithm, not SQL sintax) Given all the algorithm attempts I made, it seems I can't escape from needing to know if the last day in the database is part of the current week or not (or, as is in my question, to know which is the first day of the current week so I can compare with the database's last entry), but how to know that? I could do a manual calculation such as: pick the current day and correspondent day of the week, subtract x days till I reach the current week's Monday and see if that is the day stored in the database¹, but I'ld like to know if there is a smarter code then that I'm missing.

---

¹: Something like this:

```
const QDate lastRecordDate = QDateTime::fromString(query.record().value(0).toString(),DOWNLOAD_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT).date();
const QDate currDate = QDate::currentDate();
const qint32 dayOfWeek = currDate.dayOfWeek();
const qint32 daysDiff = Qt::Monday - dayOfWeek;
const QDate firstDayOfThisWeek = currDate.addDays(daysDiff);

if (lastRecordDate != firstDayOfThisWeek)
    createWeeksRecord = true;
```

Comment: "subtract x days till I reach the current week's Monday" Just to complicate things, many countries use Sunday as the first day of the week.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#firstDayOfWeek Solves my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `weekNumber()` method on QDate.

```
const QDate lastRecordDate = QDateTime::fromString(query.record().value(0).toString(),DOWNLOAD_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT).date();
const QDate currDate = QDate::currentDate();
if (lastRecordDate.weekNumber() != currDate.weekNumber())
{
    // Insert new record here.
}
else
{
    // Update record here.
}
```